# Call a generic method with a generic method

Tags: c#, generics

I am annoyed because I would like to call a generic method from a another generic method..

Here is my code:

```
public List<Y> GetList<Y>(
                string aTableName,
                bool aWithNoChoice)
{
  this.TableName = aTableName;
  this.WithNoChoice = aWithNoChoice;

  DataTable dt = ReturnResults.ReturnDataTable("spp_GetSpecificParametersList", this);

  //extension de la classe datatable
  List<Y> resultList = (List<Y>)dt.ToList<Y>();

  return resultList;  
}
```

So in fact when I call ToList who is an extension to DataTable class (learned [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4192968/linq-to-map-a-datatable-into-a-listmyobject))

The compiler says that Y is not a non-abstract Type and he can't use it for .ToList<> generic method..

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks for reading..

Comment: Maybe start with compilable code? I assume it should be `dt.AsEnumerable().ToList<T>()`

Comment: @Henk Holterman: The OP appears to be using a custom extension-method, not the LINQ to Objects `Enumerable.ToList` method.

Comment: @Ani: I guess so, but that would be something to mention.

Comment: @Henk Holterman "..I call ToList who is an extension to DataTable class (learned Here)" This is the mention..

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Change the method signature to:

```
public List<Y> GetList<Y>(
                string aTableName,
                bool aWithNoChoice) where Y: new()
```

The reason you need that is because the custom extension-method you use imposes the `new()` constraint on its generic type argument. It certainly needs to, since it creates *instances* of this type to populate the returned list.

Obviously, you will also have to *call* this method with a generic type argument that represents a non-abstract type that has a public parameterless constructor.

Answer (score 5):

It sounds like you need:

```
public List<Y> GetList<Y>(
     string aTableName,
     bool aWithNoChoice) where Y : class, new()
{ ... }
```

Comment: what is difference between WHERE Y : new() and where Y: class, new()? Thanks for response!

Comment: @bAN - `where Y : class` ensures that `Y` is a *reference type* (most likely, a `class`). Actually you might not need this - re-reading the linked `ToList` it just needs `where Y : new()`, so @Ani's answer is correct.

Answer (score 4):

It looks like the ToList function has a constraint on the type:

```
where T : new()
```

I think that if you use that same constraint on your function (but with `Y` instead of `T`) it should work.

You can read more about it here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sd2w2ew5(v=VS.80).aspx

Answer (score 1):

I guess you need to constraints on your generic type by using where clause.