# ADO.NET Bind to Strongly Typed Object (List)?

Tags: linq, reflection, types, sqldatareader

I can create ab object in .NET 4, run a DataReader over a sproc result, and then bind the DataReader to the properties of a new object and then add it to a List. But that lacks some "cool factor" in 2011.... Does anyone know of a decent way to do that "better"? I am not looking to use Linq to SQL or Entity Framework, no GUIs necessary. Just a new/better way to simply bind TDS output to a collection of objects.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question [LINQ to map a datatable into a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4192968/linq-to-map-a-datatable-into-a-listmyobject) has an answer which would allow you to add an extension method, letting you do this in a one-liner which is definitely 2011.