# How to correctly use soap webservice client in c#

Tags: c#, web-services, soap

I am new to c# and trying to consume a SOAP web service, I generated a service reference to the WSDL and am able to do the following to retrieve a DataSet of the response.

```
SportingGatewaySoapClient myServices = new SportingGatewaySoapClient("GatewaySoapID");

RSportResults sportsResults = myServices.SportResults("username","password");
System.Data.DataSet dataSet = sportsResults.dsSportResults;
```

I am able to see the correct information if I iterate through the dataset like you would normally :

```
foreach (DataTable table in dataSet.Tables)
{
    foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
    {
        foreach (object item in row.ItemArray)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item);
        }
    }
}
```

But I am failing to see how I can Unmarshall the data directly into the generated classes so I can reference its properties by name. eg :

```
 // some code here to convert response to a Sport object
 sport.getSportName()
```

The auto generated Reference.cs file has classes like this :

```
/// <remarks/>
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Xml", "4.7.3056.0")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(Namespace="https://endpointurl")]
public partial class RSport : object, System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged {

    private string sportName;
```

What step am I missing here?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [LINQ to map a datatable into a list<MyObject>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4192968/linq-to-map-a-datatable-into-a-listmyobject)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your WCF return a `DataSet` which contains the `RSport` objects.

So the idea to create an extension for `DataTable`. This extension using `Reflection` will convert each row into an instance of given type

```
public static class DataTableExtensions
{
    public static IList<T> ToList<T>(this DataTable table) where T : new()
    {
        IList<PropertyInfo> properties = typeof(T).GetProperties().ToList();
        IList<T> result = new List<T>();

        foreach (var row in table.Rows)
        {
            var item = CreateItemFromRow<T>((DataRow)row, properties);
            result.Add(item);
        }

        return result;
    }


    private static T CreateItemFromRow<T>(DataRow row, IList<PropertyInfo> properties) where T : new()
    {
        T item = new T();
        foreach (var property in properties)
        {
            property.SetValue(item, row[property.Name], null);
        }
        return item;
    }
}
```

Next, you convert your datatable like this

```
System.Data.DataSet dataSet = sportsResults.dsSportResults;
var rs = dataSet.Tables[0].ToList<RSport>();
```

That is the way to fetch the data

Comment: Thanks! that is a great helper method.

Comment: @Fuzz glad to help you.:) One upvote will make my day