# Can you bind Property Grid to a data source?

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio-2010

New to c# i was wondering if you can bind a sql or access data table to a property grid? I'm using Vs2010.

Comment: quite different from a regular gridview, but seems to be possible (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.databindings.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Are you restricted to using a DataTable?  Or could you convert it to a generic list, then bind the Property Grid control to that?

1. [Convert DataTable to Generic List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4104464/convert-datatable-to-generic-list-in-c-sharp)
2. [Bind To Property Grid](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/mgold/PropertyGridInCSharp11302005004139AM/PropertyGridInCSharp.aspx)