# How to databind using propertyGrid?

Tags: c#, database, propertygrid

How do you databind tables in a database to `PropertyGrid` to view/change its property values? I am not able to find how you databind a whole database to `PropertyGrid`, only classes or objects.

Comment: you probably want a `DataGridView`

Comment: Is there any way you could do it with PropertyGrid? I want to be able to see the type and change the values.

Comment: Convert columns of the `DataTable` to the custom class

Comment: visit this link, I hope it will helps you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10421816/can-you-bind-property-grid-to-a-data-source