# Filling a List<string> with MySQL Query

Tags: c#, mysql, string, list, combobox

I'm trying to fill a ComboBox with a list. A list that I would previously fill with data from my database using the "SELECT code FROM country;" as a query.

```
      string MyConString =
         "SERVER=localhost;" +
         "DATABASE=world;" +
         "username=root;" +
         "PASSWORD=1111;";

        string sql = "SELECT code FROM country;";


        MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(MyConString);
        MySqlCommand cmdSel = new MySqlCommand(sql, connection);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmdSel);
        da.Fill(dt);

        List<string> data = new List<string>();
```

How to fill data? I've tried a lot of stuff, it just does not work atm.

Comment: Show what have you tried as well and explain how it _does not work_ exactly.

Comment: *it just does not work atm* can you elaborate?

Comment: you have whole DataTable full of data, do your stuff with it.

Comment: Just loop through the query results and add what you want to the list.

Comment: loop through or use linq, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4104464/convert-datatable-to-generic-list-in-c-sharp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Calling `AsEnumerable` on a `DataTable` returns an object which implements the generic `IEnumerable<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb552415.aspx), so since you have just one column, I think this should work;

```
List<string> data = dt.AsEnumerable()
                      .Select(r => r.Field<string>("code"))
                      .ToList();
```