# How can I populate a generic list of string with the results from a single-column DataTable?

Tags: c#, foreach, datatable, generic-list, asenumerable

I see a lot of complex examples for converting a DataTable with multiple-member rows [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4104464/convert-datatable-to-generic-list-in-c-sharp) but in my case, the query simply returns one column from a table, that is to say 0..N strings/varchars, such as:

```
bbfinaleofseem@wallacestevens.org
eyenoy@dunbar.com
```

I thought something like this should work:

```
DataTable UnitReportPairEmailValsDT = new DataTable();
string qry = string.Format(SQL.UnitReportPairEmailQuery, unit, rptId);
UnitReportPairEmailValsDT = SQL.ExecuteSQLReturnDataTable(
    qry,
    CommandType.Text,
    null
    );

List<String> emailAddresses = new List<string>();
foreach (string emailaddr in UnitReportPairEmailValsDT)
{
    emailAddresses.Add(emailaddr);
}
```

...but it won't compile ("*foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type 'System.Data.DataTable' because 'System.Data.DataTable' does not contain a public definition for 'GetEnumerator'*")

I tried appending ".AsEnumerable" to "in UnitReportPairEmailValsDT" too, but that also provoked the wrath of the compiler.

Comment: `List<string> dbNames = myDT.AsEnumerable().Select(n => n.Field<string>("Name")).ToList();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Error says you cannot loop through `DataTable` object itself, probably what you need is  looping through `DataRows`.

Use this.

```
foreach(DataRow row in UnitReportPairEmailValsDT.Rows)
{
     emailAddresses.Add(row["emailaddr"].ToString()); // assuming you have emailaddr column.
}
```

Other option, use `Linq`

```
emailAddresses = UnitReportPairEmailValsDT
                         .AsEnumerable()
                         .Select(row=> row.Field<string>("emailaddr"))
                         .ToList();
```

Answer (score 2):

try something like this:

```
List<String> emailAddresses = new List<string>();
foreach (DataRow row in UnitReportPairEmailValsDT.Rows)
{
    emailAddresses.Add(row.Item(0));
}
```

Comment: You mean "row.Item(0)" instead of "dr.Item(0)" right?

Comment: This works (compiles, anyway): emailAddresses.Add(dr[0].ToString());

Answer (score 1):

Suppose dt is your data table then using Linq: 
dt.Rows.Select(x=> x[0]+"").ToList() will give you List. Beware of using Select(x=>xToString()) as it is prone to error if column value is null. x[0]+"" makes sure that in case of null empty string is returned.