# How to convert DataTable to List<KeyValuePair<string, int>>

Tags: c#, list, datatable

I have a `DataTable` with 4 Columns (`Name`, `Contact`, `Address`, `Marks`). I want to convert my `DataTable` to a `List<KeyValuePair<String, int>>`. I would like to add `Name` and `Marks` in that. I was looking at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1427484/convert-datatable-to-listt) but there is no exact answer to what I'm after.

Can someone please tell me how I could convert the data table without using Linq. The List could have duplicate records so I am thinking to use Tuple. If it is possible with that then please help me with some examples.

Comment: *Why* do you not want to use LINQ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should do it. dt is of course the name of your datatable. You might also want to do dr["ColName"] instead of dr[0] :)

```
    List<KeyValuePair<String, int>> test = new List<KeyValuePair<string, int>>();
    foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
    {
        test.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, int>(dr[0].ToString(), Convert.ToInt16(dr[3])));
    }
```

Comment: Thank you. You have made my day.

Answer (score 0):

This is off my head but:

```
public static List<KeyValuePair<string, int>> ConvertRowsToList(DataTable input) {
  var ret = new List<KeyValuePair<string, int>>();

  foreach(DataRow dr in input.Rows)
    ret.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, int>((string)dr["Name"], (int)dr["Marks"]));

  return ret;
}
```