# export multiple table with ssis

Tags: sql-server, ssis, export-to-excel

I have 2 tables are like this (Table1 and Table2)

```
ID  NAME             No      Addrress     Notes
------------        ----------------------------
1   John            111      USA          Done
2   Steve           222      Brazil       Done
```

Now I want to create a SSIS package which will create a csv file like:

```
Table1;ID;NAME             
Table2;No;Addrress;Notes  
"Detail1";"1";"John";"2";"Steve"           
"Detail2";"111";"USA";"Done";"222";"Brazil";"Done"
```

Can we achieve the same output? I have searched on google but haven't found any solution.

Please help ....

Comment: Looks simple enough but I wonder why you would want this format?

Comment: This file needed by SAP for integration data

Comment: Isn't there a SAP migration tool that uses SQL Server? Or like a SAP connector for SSIS? Do you absolutely have no choice but to export to csv in this format first?

Comment: What have you tried so far? One way of solving it is casting the resulting set from the tables to XML and replacing characters for the tags to csv separators.

Comment: If you are using SQL Server 2017 you can use String_agg().

Comment: When looking at your output for a csv, it strikes me that SAP is expecting a concateneation of key-value pairs. You could make a function in C# in a dataflow transformation inside your SSIS package that converts each of the columns to a key value pair and then adds them to some output column. See this example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14495679/how-to-convert-datatable-to-listkeyvaluepairstring-int

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You really should put in your question what you have tried so far, it helps out a lot and makes it more fun to help people.

The two ways I can think of in t-sql to solve this still need you to specify in your code what your column names are. You can get around this with using dynamic SQL and creating a view that spits out data in the same fashion for all the tables you need.

If SSIS is more your thing you could use the dynamic approach with BIML.

```
--Option 1 (SQL Server 2008 R2 and later)
with Table1 AS (
SELECT * FROM (values(1,'John'),(2,'Steve')) AS x(ID,NAME)
)
,Table2 AS (
SELECT * FROM (values(111,'USA','Done'),(222,'Brazil','Done'))AS y(No,Addrress,Notes)
)
SELECT '"Detail1"'+ CAST(foo as VARCHAR(4000))
FROM (
SELECT ';"' + CAST(ID AS VARCHAR(4))+'";"' + [NAME] +'"'  FROM Table1 FOR XML PATH('')
) AS bar(foo)
UNION ALL
SELECT '"Detail2"'+ CAST(foo as VARCHAR(4000))
FROM (
SELECT ';"' + CAST([No] AS VARCHAR(4))+'";"' + [Addrress] +'";"' + [Notes] +'"'  FROM Table2 FOR XML PATH('')
) AS bar(foo)



--Option 2 (SQL Server 2017 and later)
with Table1 AS (
SELECT * FROM (values(1,'John'),(2,'Steve')) AS x(ID,NAME)
)
,Table2 AS (
SELECT * FROM (values(111,'USA','Done'),(222,'Brazil','Done'))AS y(No,Addrress,Notes)
)
SELECT '"Detail1";' + STRING_AGG('"'+CAST(ID AS varchar(4))+'";"'+[NAME]+'"',';') FROM Table1
UNION ALL
SELECT '"Detail2";' + STRING_AGG('"'+CAST([No] AS varchar(4))+'";"'+[Addrress]+'";'+'"'+[Notes]+'"',';') FROM Table2
;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a `script task` to generate a CSV file for you which can handle your issue:

You can try this:

```
 SqlConnection sqlCon = new SqlConnection("Server=localhost;Initial Catalog=LegOgSpass;Integrated Security=SSPI;Application Name=SQLNCLI11.1");

        sqlCon.Open();
        SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand(@"Select ID,Name from dbo.Table1", sqlCon);
        SqlDataReader reader = sqlCmd.ExecuteReader();


        string fullpath = @"C:\Users\thoje\Desktop\stack\New folder\table1.csv";
        StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fullpath);
        object[] output = new object[reader.FieldCount];

        for (int i = 0; i < reader.FieldCount; i++)
            output[i] = reader.GetName(i);

        sw.WriteLine(@"Table1;"+string.Join(";", output));

        List<object> values = new List<object>();
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            reader.GetValues(output);

            values.Add($"\"{output[0]}\"");
            values.Add($"\"{output[1]}\"");



        }

        sw.WriteLine(@"""Detail1"";"+ string.Join(";", values));
        sw.Flush();
        sw.Close();
        reader.Close();
        sqlCon.Close();


        Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
```

**Result:**

[image]