# Easy way to convert Datatable to List using C#

Tags: c#, linq

I am trying to convert Datatable to List using C# like this

```
public void GetList()
{

    ds = // here my dataset;

    List<MasterList> result = new List<MasterList>();
    if (ds.Tables.Count > 0 && ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        foreach (DataRow dt in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
        {
            result.Add(new MasterList()
            {
                Name = Convert.ToString(dt["Name"]),
                Address = Convert.ToString(dt["Address"]),
                City = Convert.ToString(dt["City"])
            });

        }
    }
}
```

this code is working fine, but I want to know easy way to convert Datatable to List and here used foreach loop.

so what's solution for this ?

Comment: 1s google http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1427484/convert-datatable-to-listt

Comment: or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/208532/how-do-you-convert-a-datatable-into-a-generic-list

Answer (score 3):

With Linq you can do the following:

```
List<MasterList> result = ds.Tables[0].AsEnumerable().Select(dtRow => new MasterList()
{
    Name = Convert.ToString(dtRow["Name"]),
    Address = Convert.ToString(dtRow["Address"]),
    City = Convert.ToString(dtRow["City"])
}).ToList()
```